# Unable to make restTemplate call with Generics for nested Json

Tags: java, generics, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I am trying to make a restTemplate call for API testing. The json returned is a nested one with multiple levels.

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "result": {
      "publicId": "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following classes acting as wrapper :

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public abstract class RestCallResponse<T> {

    private int code;

    protected RestCallResponse(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    protected RestCallResponse(){}

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Map<?, ?> getRestCallResponse() {
        return ImmutableMap.of("result", getResult());
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    protected abstract T getResult();

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

And then a `SuccessRestResponse` class extending this abstract class :

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class SuccessRestResponse<T> extends RestCallResponse<T> {

    @JsonProperty("result")
    private T result;

    public SuccessRestResponse() {

    }

    public SuccessRestResponse(T result) {
        super(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
        this.result = result;
    }

    protected T getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }

}
```

Then finally I have the actual data POJO :

```
public final class CreatedResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    private final EntityId publicId;

    public CreateCreativeResponse(EntityId publicId) {
        this.publicId = publicId;
    }
}
```

In the test case, I am making a call as such :

```
ResponseEntity<SuccessRestResponse<CreatedResponse>> newResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<SuccessRestResponse<CreatedResponse>>() {});
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: null value in entry: result=null (through reference chain: com.inmobi.helix.test.api.dao.SuccessRestResponse["data"]);
```

Any suggestions? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a workaround. Still don't know what's wrong with the above piece of code though. 
I got rid of the class `RestCallResponse<T>` and edited the field members in `SuccessRestResponse<T>` to look like this :

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class SuccessRestResponse<T> {

    private int code;
    private Map<String, T> data;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Map<String, T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public T getResult() {
        return data.get("result");
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This corresponds to the nested json while deserialization.

> P.S. - Would still like to know what went wrong in my above code
>   though. As in, why did class hierarchy not work for me.